# Can I Install NPM Packages Using Sudo?

Tags: npm, npm-install, sudo

I was recently prompted to install a patch of NPM using `npm install -g npm`, though this process fails. Below are excerpts from the error message.

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
```

and

```
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Is it safe to install the patch using sudo? If not what is the proper fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but no, it is not safe. Lots of people do it, but they shouldn't. If you install with `sudo`, then all the package's dependencies and subdependencies (which can be a very large number of packages) can run lifecycle scripts as root, basically doing anything they want. You can mitigate that with `--ignore-scripts` but then things you install might not work.

The better solutions are in [the npm docs about this topic](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally): Install `node` and `npm` with a version manager (like [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)) or configure `npm` to do global installs in a directory where you will not need to use `sudo`.

All that said, for your specific situation--just updating `npm` itself--using `sudo` is a very common solution despite being one that is not all that advisable. Installing `npm` with a version manager is a better idea if you are on a development machine (like your personal laptop).